# iOS - Distributed applications plist

Tags: ios, xcode, git, repository, plist

I'm using git with an iPad xcode project.

I have an application settings plist file (`AppSettings.plist`) that is included in the projects repo.

I'd like my devs to have this starting `AppSettings.plist` when they do a fresh clone but I wouldn't like this file to be committed each time it's updated, so each dev can keep their own version.

I though about .gitignoring it and supply an `AppSettings.plist.dist` but how could we remember the builder guy to update this file each time we want to have him to ?

Answer (score 0):

So you do not just want a static template of the file, but you also want to modify the file and get these modifications merged into the working copy?

*Note:* Let’s call `AppSettings.plist` “working copy” and `AppSettings.plist.dist` “Template”

My proposal would be to add a version number to the file. When you do changes in the repo, you increase the version number. Then when building you check these numbers in the working copy and the template and emit an error if they don’t match.

If you don’t care about newer/older, you can also use [git’s ident feature](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_%3Ctt%3Eident%3C/tt%3E). That will add the blob id of the template to on checkout. If that id is not the same in the working copy, it is obviously not based on that template.